# Why does my child class not initialize variables properly in java

Tags: java, subclass

In the code below, myString is always initialized to null. I have to manually initialize in an init() or similar. As far as I can tell it is related to superclass/subclass but I don't understand the exact mechanism

```
public class A extends B {

    private String myString = "test";


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A();
    }

    public A() {
        super();

    }

    public void c() {
        System.out.println(myString);
    }

}

public class B {

    public B() {
        c();
    }

    public void c() {

    }
}
```

Comment: With the code posted `new A()` will *always* set the `myString` private variable to "test" *before* the constructor for `A` is invoked. See Hovercraft's comment.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Inside a constructor do as little as possible to initialize the object and avoid calling public/protected methods of your own (because they might be overridden and this might lead to hard to find bugs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your code is, that `myString` is initialized at the begin of the constructor of class `A` but right **after** the super constructor (i.e. class `B`). Since you access the variable before from the constructor of class `B` (indirectly via call to overriden methode `c`) your get this behaviour.

As a rule of thumb: if you want to avoid unexpected behavior do not call overriden methods before the constructor has been executed.

Comment: Is there a "correct" way to do what I'm trying to such that I can initialize my variables at the beginning of my code for A instead of via a special init method?

Comment: @deltanovember in your case (constant variable) it is sufficient to declare the variable as `static`. Otherwise I would suggest to follow the path you suggested and use a method `init` which does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Add a call to `c();` overidden method right after the object has been fully created and call to superclass constructor is done.

Change your code to this ..

```
public class A extends B {

    private String myString = "test";


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A();
    }

    public A() {
        super();
         c();     // Include the call to c(); here ...

    }

    public void c() {
        System.out.println(myString);
    }

}

public class B {

    public B() {

    }

    public void c() {

    }
} 

 // Output : test
```

Comment: The main thing is I want the base class to do the architectural stuff. For example I might want vehicle to call switchOn(), drive(), brake() and leave implementation details to the subclasses

Answer (score 0):

Thinking in Java Second Edition by Bruce Eckel, Behavior of polymorphic methods
inside constructors (p. 337-339).